# What is the easiest way to set all the inputs on a page to seperate data-theme than the page data-them in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a webpage with the page div set to data-theme D

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="d">
```

I also have several inputs on the page with the data-theme set to A

```
<input data-theme='a' type='text'>
<input data-theme='a' type='text'>
<input data-theme='a' type='text'>
```

Is there an easier way to set all the input's data-theme's to A without having to set each input individually?

Comment: do you want all inputs to have `a` theme, in all pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1- Solution 1:**

Wrap them in `data-role="content"`, but this will change the background color of the div.

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/6cnX6/)**

---

**2- Solution 2:**

Globally, set theme to all `input` on `mobileinit` event.

```
<head>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
      $.mobile.textinput.prototype.options.theme = "a";
    });
  </script>
  <script src="jquery.mobile.js"></script>
</head>
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/6WnEU/)**

---

**3- Solution 3:**

Set `input` theme on `pagebeforecreate`.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", function () {
    $("input").textinput({
        "theme": "a"
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/fVwwm/)**